# Showing Stirling's approximation up to a constant

Tags: calculus

I am trying to derive a 'rough' version of Stirling's approximation for $N!$:
$$
N!\approx c\sqrt{N}\Big(\frac{N}{e}\Big)^N.\tag{1}
$$
I'm aware that Stirling's approximation has $c=\sqrt{2\pi}$, but I'm just trying to obtain (1) at the moment.

**What I've done:** I have shown already that
$$
\int_1^N\frac{\{x\}}{x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^N\ln n-N\ln N+N-1\tag2
$$
in my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066706/integral-of-int-1n-frac-x-xdx). By $\{x\}$ I refer to the Fractional Part of $x$, where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

I noticed that by applying $\exp$ to the summation in (2), I get $N!$, so I wonder how I can simplify all of this to show (1).

A hint that I am given is to start by showing that
$$
\int_1^N\frac{\{x\}}{x}dx=\frac{\ln N}2+\mathcal O(1/N)+C,\tag{3}
$$
for some constant $C$. The equality in (3) above looks like it can be simplified somehow to (1), I think, because for example we have
$$
\exp((\ln N)/2)=\exp(\ln(N^{1/2}))=\sqrt{N},
$$
which gets me the $\sqrt N$ factor in (1). But beyond that I am a little stuck on how to piece everything together. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute the RHS of (3) into the LHS of (2):
$$
\frac{{\log N}}{2} + C + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{N}} \right) = \underbrace {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\log n} }_{\log N!} - N\log N + N - 1.
$$
Taking the exponential of both sides gives
$$
\sqrt N e^C e^{\mathcal{O}\left( {\frac{1}{N}} \right)}  = N!N^{ - N} e^N e^{ - 1} .
$$
Re-ordering and calling $c=e^{C+1}$ gives
$$
N! = c\sqrt N \left( {\frac{N}{e}} \right)^N e^{\mathcal{O}\left( {\frac{1}{N}} \right)} .
$$
By the Taylor series of the exponential function
$$
e^{\mathcal{O}\left( {\frac{1}{N}} \right)}  = 1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{N}} \right).
$$
Thus, finally,
$$
N! = c\sqrt N \left( {\frac{N}{e}} \right)^N \left( {1 +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{N}} \right)} \right).
$$